# How to disable alert dialogs when errors occur in Atom Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

Is there a way to disable alert dialogs when errors occur in Electron App, or better yet disable ALL dialogs?

Dialogs are useless in headless mode (granted electron is not intended to be a headless app) and just get things stuck.

I'm not necessarily looking for a flag 'disable_dialogs'. Perhaps I could override one method in the main process so that dialogs don't open?

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-disable-alert-dialogs-when-errors-occur/20037

Comment: Yep, but no explanation on how to override the method to log to the console instead of the default behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone has left the following on that discussion thread.

[Disable error dialogs by overriding](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-disable-alert-dialogs-when-errors-occur/20037/4)

```
const electron = require('electron');
const dialog = electron.dialog;

// Disable error dialogs by overriding
dialog.showErrorBox = function(title, content) {
    console.log(`${title}\n${content}`);
};
```

Comment: What file am I making these changes in?

Comment: That depends. :)

It *could* be that you have some file called main.js that contains the first code that gets run when your main process starts.

That *could* be a good place to rebind this, near the top of that main.js.

I don't have your code in front of me nor know under what conditions you want to enable this behaviour, so I *could* be wrong. :)

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md